# Passing objects into SystemVerilog tasks/functions - Vivado Zynq Verification IP / API

Tags: system-verilog, vivado

I have a testbench in Vivado which has a hierarchy of IP--some custom IP and some Xilinx IP, like the Zynq Processing System. The Zynq Processing System also has an associated Verification IP library that has useful API for doing things like loading DDR.

I would like to write a task which leverages the Zynq Verification IP (and associated API) inside it. I can't figure out how I would implement this in my testbench? I am new to SV, and am guessing that I need to pass the zynq processing system object as an argument so I can access it's API inside my super-task.

**Updated example** of what I'm trying to do in my testbench. I realize this isn't proper SystemVerilog, it's just to demonstrate the functionality I'm trying to obtain. TOP is a module defined in some other .sv file that contains the definition of a task called T:

```
module tb();

  TOP TIPTOP(), TIPITTYTOP();

  task myTask(input TOP T);
    begin
        T.T;
    end
  endtask
  
initial begin
  
  myTask(TIPTOP);
  myTask(TIPITTYTOP);
  
end
  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer to the updated question

This can only be done if the module TOP is not a module but a different flavour of module, called an *interface*. There is a special kind of SystemVerilog variable called a *virtual interface* which is a variable that can store a reference to the instance of an interface. This is what you need here. So,

1. you need to make TOP an interface and
2. you need to add the keyword `virtual` to your task: `task myTask(input virtual TOP T);`

There are restrictions on an interface, however. (We are not quite using it for its normal purpose here.) The main one which might affect you is that you cannot instantiate a module inside an interface.

---

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/SM33

```
interface TOP;
  task T;
    $display("TOP.T");
  endtask
endinterface

module tb();

  TOP TIPTOP(), TIPITTYTOP();

  task myTask(input virtual TOP T);
    begin
        T.T;
    end
  endtask
  
initial begin
  
  myTask(TIPTOP);
  myTask(TIPITTYTOP);
  
end
  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a task or function that is declared in another module. The code below has the following structure:

```
P

  TOP       ANOTHER_TOP           
   |            |
BOT bot      BOT bot
```

Package `P` and all modules have a task `T` declared in them. I can call all of the tasks from module `TOP`:

I can call the task in the package `P` using the *score resolution operator*, `::`:

```
P::T;
```

I can call the local task:

```
T;
```

I can call the task in the instance `bot` of `BOT`:

```
bot.T;
```

I can call the task in the other top-level module, `ANOTHER_TOP`:

```
ANOTHER_TOP.T;
```

I can call the task in the instance `bot` of `BOT` in the other top-level module:

```
ANOTHER_TOP.bot.T;
```

Notice how I have declared the various a tasks and modules "in the wrong order". This is OK, because Verilog takes 3 passes to compile and the relationships between the various tasks and modules are sorted out in passes 2 and 3. The package, however, has to be compiled first. This is because packages are a bit of an after-thought in the grand scheme of things.

---

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/KpJR

```
package P;
  task T;
    $display("P::T");
  endtask
endpackage

module TOP;
  initial
    begin
      T;
      ANOTHER_TOP.T;
      bot.T;
      ANOTHER_TOP.bot.T;
      P::T;
    end
  task T;
    $display("TOP.T");
  endtask
  BOT bot ();
endmodule

module ANOTHER_TOP;
  task T;
    $display("ANOTHER_TOP.T");
  endtask
  BOT bot ();
endmodule

module BOT;
  task T;
    $display("BOT.T");
  endtask
endmodule
```

Comment: That is such a useful tool, I didn't know about that. Actually what I'm trying to do is have the TIPTOP object in myTask() be callable with other T instances, not just the TIPTOP instance. I don't want to have to rewrite this task for each object instance. How can I pass it as an argument to achieve this? I updated the question's example above